# Second router in a home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have a wireless router (*Huawei EchoLife HG521*), given by the ISP which isn't quite powerful. In two rooms away the signal drops significantly and it's rather hard to connect wirelessly.

I have found a second wireless router(*Pirelli Discus Wireless VoIP AGv1-t Annex A-OT*) from another ISP(I suppose all the ISP's setting are loaded) I used to have a few years ago.

What can I do to place the second router in my room so that I can use both routers using my current ISP.

Comment: How to do it depends on the type of router you're going to add. But it involves setting the second router as acces-point. Disable its DHCP, set a manual ip-adres and plug the cable from your main router in one of the LAN-ports (not the WAN-port). Or if it's a broadband router (not DSL-modem) you **can** use the WAN-port and it will get its own ip-adres.

Comment: @Rik: Thank you very much for your comment! What do you mean by *type of router*? How to set it as access point and how to disable its DHCP, set a manula IP? As you can understand I am a total novice in networking...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the *Pirelli AGv1-t Annex A-OT* is a (A)DSL-modem. You probably can't use the WAN-port (DSL-port) of that model. It's best to set a static ip adres on this device.

- First check what the ip from your current router is. This is normally the `Default gateway` address from your current computer. (start `cmd.exe` and type `ipconfig`, the `Default gateway` is somewhere at the top)
- Disconnect your computer and connect it to the Pirelli. Restart your computer. (or disable your network interface and re-enable it again to let your computer get an ip address from it.)
- Goto the web-interface of the Pirelli. (Usually 192.168.1.1 but it can differ)
- Goto `Network-connections`
- Deactivate the `WAN DSL`-interface
- Choose `WAN Bridge`
- Disable the `DHCP-server` at the bottom
- Set its ip-address to something in the range of your **main-router** (the `Default gateway` from the first step).
  For example: if that was `192.168.1.1` set your Pirelli to `192.168.1.5`.
  If that was `192.168.1.254` set it to `192.168.1.250` so only change the last number to something close to it.
- Leave the subnet mask `255.255.255.0` intact
- Leave your computer connected to the Pirelli and connect another cable from a LAN-port of the Pirelli to you main-router
- Now restart your computer and the Pirelli
- If you get internet access on your computer it works.

These instruction where created using a webinterface of a Pirelli PRG AV4202 so I don't know if the terminology is exactly the same for you.

Comment: I assume that I have to connect it through ethernet. I tried to connect either wirelessly or via cable and I am able to. The thing is that when I am using the web interface it requires a username and a password. I used the usual *admin, admin* but it's not correct. Perhaps I have changed it. Is there a way to *reset* that somehow?

Comment: Do you have a manual. Or a reset-button on the back? Usually the username/password for the "Wireless_VoIP_AG_v1" is user/user.

Comment: I don't have a manual, but I do have a reset button. I used it, but after that I can't get the wireless to work and when I plug the ethernet cable I cannot see it anymore on the network list. However vista could "mount" it and find relevant drivers.

Comment: You should plug your computer in via a cable. You shouldn't see anything in "Network list" because you should go to the web-interface with your browser (i.e. [192.168.1.1](http://192.168.1.1) if that's the `Default gateway` you got after restart when connected to the Pirelli. To get the `Default gateway` also check step 1 in the above answer. The same as getting the ip of your main router)

Comment: I followed your instructions, but there is no internet connection. I logged in the router using `ONTadmiN` as name and `#ONt@Dm1n4P!0` as pass. I coludn't find `Network-Connections` but I was able to "change" the IP via `LAN Settings` http://i.imgur.com/EZpFQCD.jpg after loading the factory settings. I connected the router to my room's phone line but there is no internet at all. Note that I used a filter between the router and the line.

Comment: You need to connect the second router (Pirelli) via ethernet cable. A normal phone cable won't work. And I don't know what you mean by "filter" but you need to connect both routers via the LAN-ports to each other (with an ethernet cable).

Comment: What I want to do is place the Pirelli router in my room, in the phone line plug. The first wireless router is in the living room and the ethernet connection to the second router would require making holes on the wall. By filter I mean a spliter connected to the the phone line and has as output an ADSL line and a phone line.

Comment: You did change the ip correctly but did you also disable the DHCP. If you've done that **and** connected the routers to each other via LAN it should work.

Comment: No. The connection of the HG521 are "DSL" is **input** (this is your incoming phoneline), "LAN" is **output** to a computer or second router and "Phone" is passthrough for the phoneline. You **need** to use the LAN-port to connect a second router. There is absolutely no way around that. You could use 2 converters to pass the ethernet signal through the power-lines in your house but then you'll need to buy those. I would first check with running a cable over the ground to see if you can get it working. (You can try with a small cable first)

Comment: If I connect the output of the first router(which is connected to a phoneline) to a Pirelli's LAN port it works. In that way I can connect wirelessly to the internet via the Pirelli router. So you are saying that the only ways to have a second router away from the first is either to drill the wall and pass an ethernet cable to my room or to change my house's phonelines.

Comment: You could try connecting the wires of you phone-line to the LAN-port but that would involve pinching a new plug on those wires to fit it in the LAN-port. But you get in trouble because you'll need a minimum of 4 wires. Also phone wire is of far less quality and you'll never get good speed and possible/definite interference. And you can't use your phone in your room. See [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/407530) for a discussion. You can also [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ethernet+over+phone+cable) it.

Comment: If you can live without a phone in your room you could substitute the phone cable for an ethernet cable. Or run it along side it. If there is no room for 2 cables it would even be possible to use 2 of the 8 wires for your phone leaving the other 4 (2 not used) for ethernet. But you'll need to do some fiddling with the cables (which I wouldn't recommend for a layman). BTW if it's just one wall you could bore the whole a little bigger so you can put 2 cables through.

Comment: I really don't mind having a phone in my room-at the moment I don't. And I do have great experience with cables! My goal is to have the same connections as the primary router on my room. From the phone line to the router. The only way is to turn the phone cable into an ethernet cable?

Comment: You can't have the phone-line to your router in your room. The HG521 has **no** internet signal on its *exit* phone connection. You could split the phone-line **before** the HG521 but you're only getting **one** internet signal from your provider so you can't connect two modems. So you need the ethernet-cable method. If you replace the current cable with an ethernet one or rebuild the phone cable to an ethernet cable is up to you. If you're doing the latter read up on some of the [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=ethernet+over+phone+cable) I gave you about possible downsides.

Comment: Now I see... It has to do with the ISP. So to sum up, I can only use one line for an internet connection and the the bast/fastest way to have a second wireless spot on my room is to connect both routers with an ethernet cable, right?

Comment: Yes. The phone-line (with internet signal) goes to the DSL-port of the first router. (the output phone has no internet anymore) You connect an ethernet cable in the LAN-port of that router to a LAN-port of the second router. I noticed that the HG521 has only one LAN-port so you can't connect a computer to the first via cable anymore (you used it for the second router). You can only connect wireless to the first router after that. If the Pirelli has more LAN-ports you can connect a computer via cable to that. And you can connect wireless to both routers.